# Set collection according to property value and update via AJAX

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I have an `email` object which contains a collection `textareas` and has a property `template`. The collection `textareas` contains the textareas in `template`, which are set in the controller.

```
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{       
    // Get the email
    $email = EmailQuery::create()->findPk($id);
    if (!$email)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unknown email ID.');
    }

    // If a new template file is selected, the client refreshes the form with ajax
    // So let's get the new template value
    if (isset($request->request->get('email')['template']))
    {
        if (isset($request->request->get('email')['update_with_ajax']))
            $email->setTemplate($request->request->get('email')['template']);
    }

    // Get textareas in the email's template
    $email->setTextareas($this->get('email.analyzer')->getTextAreas($email->getTemplate()));

    // Create form
    $form = $this->createForm('email', $email);

    // Handle form
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->get('save')->isClicked())
    {
        $form->save();
    }
}
```

This is my email type (which is a service):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class EmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Read template files in dir and store names in $templates
        // $templates = array();

        $builder->add('template', 'choice', array('choices' => $templates);
        $builder->add('textareas', 'collection');
        $builder->add('save', 'submit');
        $builder->add('update_with_ajax', 'submit');
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I want to update the `textareas` collection via AJAX when the user chooses another template. As you can see I add the collection of templates to the email object before creating the form, I think that's where it all goes wrong and triggers the `This form should not contain extra fields` error. But what is the right approach?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like *$form = $this->createForm(new EmailType(), $email);*, so that the createForm has something to compare the $email too?
At least in Symfony v2.7.